# Title of TV series or movie with four armed humanoid creatures?

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for the name of a tv series or movie in the 70s, feels very British, that had some human-like creatures (maybe smaller than normal humans) that had four arms.

Comment: This is very vague, are there *any* other details you can add?

Comment: The tone of the show/movie felt like a little like the Gerry Anderson series, U.F.O., but perhaps a tad darker.

Comment: I'm looking for something like that too. The four armed alien was humanoid and the second pair of arms were small like a child's arms set under the normal adult arms. The alien used these to shrink people and would leave them in a small case. The miniaturized people would be used to produce energy, somehow. But like the original poster said, it was like a 50's or 60's sci fi flick, I remember it as being Japanese though. But it was definitely dark.

Comment: That movie is called "Wild, Wild Planet."

Answer (score 1):

The short-lived American sci-fi comedy *Quark* had a female four-armed space "telephone switchboard operator".

Comment: I will check that out, but I remember the show having a darker tone, more menacing...and perhaps even a little gothic like as if it was a Hammer film.

Answer (score 1):

The movie you're thinking of is called, "The Wild, Wild Planet," from 1965. It's actually kinda sick and messed up for a movie of that period. It's an Italian film. It was the first of a series of four films set on the Gamma 1 space station, that took place in the same universe. One of the movies was more-or-less remade as the infamous Japanese film, "The Green Slime."

[Here's the trailer for the movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SB3SszYjEmA)

Comment: The ones in the trailer don't look all that short, but it is a decent guess, and a movie I'd never seen before. That said, it looks like JP discarded it in comments for the initial question.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the description is still vague enough to cover a lot of ground.  For example, I bet you could find alien monsters-of-the-week with three, four, or more arms in more than one episode of "Voyage to the Bottom of the Sea", "Lost in Space", "Space: 1999", at least one of the "Star Trek" shows, any of the 60 or 70 years of "Doctor Who" shows, and so on.  The 1960s and 1970s saw a series of Mystery Science Theatre-worthy US/Italian/Japanese sci-fi coproduction films (including the infamous "Green Slime") that could fit the bill.  The description might fit the 80s cult horror film "The Gate" (kids play a heavy metal record backwards, open a gate to hell, and unleash a horde of little gremlin-things led by a giant 4-armed monster).  Multi-armed clay-mation nasties were standard fixtures the Harryhausen mythology films (Sinbad, Jason and the Argonauts, etc.) and elsewhere ("Equinox", for just one example).  I think the Martians from the short-lived 1980s "War of the Worlds" television show might also fit.

Any chance of remembering anything special about the outfits the creatures wore, the things they did, the setting or plot, or anything like that, which might narrow things down a bit?